# Arch Linux - Netbeans: Entering text in prompts does not work

Tags: arch-linux, netbeans

I tried the following java packages:

- extra/jdk7-openjdk
- aur/jdk

In both cases, when using Netbeans, I cannot type text in several dialogs. If I want e.g. to create a new project I cannot specify name etc.

What´s the problem? How to use Netbeans correctly under Arch Linux?

### Edit 1

- Also in the editor the cursor vanishes and typing is no more possible.

### Edit 2

- I also tried out the suggestions of the [Arch Linux Forum](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Netbeans) (e.g. changing to GTK via conf file) but then it looked even uglier than it did before and the problem was not solved.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after an update from GNOME 3.2 to GNOME 3.4. First I thought it has smth to do with GNOME, but under KDE was the same problem. The solution was to rename / delete the existing netbeans-Configuration-Folder (`/home/user/.netbeans`). I did the same with `.netbeans-derby` (don't know if necessary (or even what netbeans-derby is...)).

After a restart of NetBeans I had of course to configure it again, but auto completion works again.

Comment: Well, this really seemed to work... I´ll have to test it some more.
In meantime, I also tried sth. out with the conf file (EDIT 2).